# Passing Session ID for User Authentication

Tags: php, session, authentication

I am authenticating a set of users via an external system. That system requires the authentication done via whitelisted domains. I have a second server which is not whitelisted.

Does it make sense to redirect the user to the first domain for authentication - once authenticated, callback will authenticate the session for the user?

login *server1*

redirect *server2?cb=server1&sessionId=PHPSESSIONID*

authenticate *authentication server*

[server ] curl *server1?sessionId=PHPSESSIONID&userId=12345...* - server 2 saves to the session file the userId etc.

[client] redirect *server2* - now authenticated

Is this safe?

Comment: Did you consider use JTW?

Comment: My question is really whether there's an issue with such an implementation. Especially if it's something as simple.